# Flopy MF6 Plotting specific discharge in cross-section view

Tags: flopy

How to plot discharge vectors in cross-section view in Flopy MF6?

I know this plots for plan view:

```
quiver = mapview.plot_specific_discharge(spdis[0])
```

I tried to get specific discharge using the following code but got error:

```
AttributeError: module 'flopy.utils.postprocessing' has no attribute 'get_specific_discharge'
```

Code:

```
hds_file = os.path.join(workspace, headfile)
hds = flopy.utils.binaryfile.HeadFile(hds_file)

cbb_file = os.path.join(workspace, budgetfile)
cbb = flopy.utils.CellBudgetFile(fname, precision='double')

q = flopy.utils.postprocessing.get_specific_discharge(gwf,cbb_file, precision='single', kstpkper=(0,1),
                                                  hdsfile=hds_file, position='centers')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (using mf6) plotting specific discharge on cross sections works like this:

Reading the cbc output:

```
    cbcdobj = flopy.utils.binaryfile.CellBudgetFile(path, precision='double', verbose=True)
    SPDIS = cbcdobj.get_data(kstpkper=kstpkper, text='DATA-SPDIS')[0]
```

You might need to use 'verbose=False' and 'precision=single' when using mf2005.

Then the cross section:

```
    cros_mp=flopy.plot.PlotCrossSection(model=gwf, line={'row': 200})  
    cros_mp.plot_specific_discharge(SPDIS)
```

Remark that plotting specific discharges on an irregular cross section ('line', not 'row' nor 'column') is not possible.